# Parsing JSON response

Tags: ios, json, afnetworking

I am using `AFJSONRequestOperation` to request a remote API:

```
 NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {

        //Remove the SVProgressHUD view
        [SVProgressHUD dismiss];

        //Check for the value returned from the server

        NSData *jsonData = [JSON dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];//This line cause crash
        NSArray *arr = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData
                                                       options:0
                                                         error:nil];
        loginDic=[[NSDictionary alloc]init];
        loginDic=[arr objectAtIndex:0];
        NSLog(@"%@",loginDic);

    } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {

        NSLog(@"Request Failed with Error: %@", [error.userInfo objectForKey:@"NSLocalizedDescription"]);
    }];
    [operation start];
    [SVProgressHUD showWithStatus:@"Loading"];
```

However, the app crashes and I am getting this error:

```
[__NSCFDictionary dataUsingEncoding:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

Here is an `NSLog` for the JSON object returned:

```
 Result =     (
                {
            operation = 5;
            result = 1;
        }
    );
```

Am I missing something, because I think that I am not parsing correctly the JSON object. Please correct me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like AFJSONRequestOperation is deserializing JSON to a dictionary for you, and then you're trying to do it again. `JSON` is an NSDictionary but you're calling an NSString method.

Remove all of this code:

```
NSData *jsonData = [JSON dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];//This line cause crash
NSArray *arr = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData
                                                   options:0
                                                     error:nil];
loginDic=[[NSDictionary alloc]init];
loginDic=[arr objectAtIndex:0];
```

And replace it with:

```
loginDic = [[JSON objectForKey:@"Result"] lastObject];
```

(That'll work safely without checking array bounds, but assumes that there's only one element in the array.)

Answer (score 1):

The object you get in the success block is already parsed by `AFJSONRequestOperation`.
In your case you get a NSDictionary object.

You can check the class of the object using the `isKindofClass`-method:

```
if ([JSON isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
   NSDictionary* dict = (NSDictionary*)JSON;
   ...
}
```